# Notifications are not shown : Fcm , React , Vite

Tags: node.js, reactjs, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am facing issue in appling the FCM notification structure using react + vite app and nodejs as backend.The messages are not comming either in foreground nor in background and the onMessage Event Handler is also not working at all, nor does the firebase-messaging-sw.js file, trying from 3 days can anybodfy help.

here are some screenshots for the same , these are my file structure and the code every tutorial guided me to follow.

let's start with folder structure :

[image]

now let's see firebase.js file

[image]

let's see the file where i implemented request permission code and other things

[image]

let's see the code where i implemented the registration of serviceWorker file:

[image][image]

now let's see the service worker file:

[image]

I tried everything in given in. may video tutorials , firebase documentation and other articles also , they recommended similar procejudre and i followed that only.

In the main peoject i am sending this token to my nodejs server where i am programatically sending the notification messages and it is working fine the messages are going but not showing on any device due to same reason :(.

what is happening :Only the token is printing and nothing else is happening

what is expected : a background notification or even a console log

Comment: how did you resolve it?